# How to respond to an Android notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I found a way to read the notifications from the Android status bar, but I want to also be able to respond to the ones that support the "reply" option. How can I do that? I see that, for example, Pebble watch has the possibility to respond to such messages. I found this resource, it's good for the notification reading part, but I did not manage to send a response: https://medium.com/@polidea/how-to-respond-to-any-messaging-notification-on-android-7befa483e2d7#.q8tklp3jk

Comment: I am also looking to do this. When a device needs to pair, Android has this annoying behavior where sometimes it pops up a dialog where the user can respond to the request but other times it sends a notification and the user has to draw down the notification drawer and then click on it to get the dialog. I would like to programmatically 'click' on that notification so the user sees ONLY the popup dialog.